# Adding additional Class to Landuse Map in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, land-use

I'm using ArcGIS Pro.

I have a landuse raster with 8 unique classes.

[image: Main Raster with 8 classes]

I have another raster with 1 unique class which I would like to go over my main raster (replacing everything on top of it) to become the 9th class

[image: What I'm trying to do...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Raster Calculator tool with the `Con` and `IsNull` functions to set the output raster to the existing landuse value where proposed landuse is null, otherwise set to 9.

Note: make sure you set the tool environment processing extent and snap raster if the rasters have different dimensions.

`Con(IsNull("PROPOSED"),  "LANDUSE", 9)`

[image]

[image]